# Mixing ControllerAS with $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

For all new work I use the `ControllerAs` syntax so that I can refer to the controller as `vm` within my views.  Which is great.

However I still a large portion of old code that uses the `$scope` syntax.  In particular one of my directives uses `ng-click="groupClick"` which would usually call the `groupClick` function on the `$scope` of the parent controller.  This view is being built with the `ContollerAs` syntax so this doesn't work anymore.

The existing code looks like this (simplified)

```
<span>{{vm.somePropertyOnController}}</span>

<!-- This is provided by a template I cannot change -->
<a href="" ng-click="groupClick(item)">Test</a>
```

How can I get the `<a>` (which is provided via a template I cannot change) to call `vm.groupClick`.  I'd ideally not like to add `$scope` to my controller simply to get `groupClick` working

My controller code:

```
var vm = this;

vm.somePropertyOnController = "yay vm is cool";

// i really dont want to do this! dont make me!
$scope.groupClick = function (group) { console.log("test"); }
```

Comment: Well, `vm.groupClick(item)` should do it. It's ugly to bind the directive to a specific controller that way, but it was already the case with scope.

Comment: It would do, but I cannot change the template

Comment: Then you're calling a function on the scope, and this function must thus be on the scope. Add `$scope.groupClick = function(item) {vm.groupClick(item);}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your groupClick function:

```
vm.groupClick = groupClick

function groupClick() {
    console.log('test')
}
```

In the view, you would have to use the controllerAs syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName as ctrl">
    <span>{{ctrl.somePropertyOnController}}</span>
    <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.groupClick(item)">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot change the template (aka the `<a>`) as it is used extensively throughout the app and I dont have time right now to do this change and do a full regression